# Rotate to Portrait Orientation when back button pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rotation, landscape, portrait

Hey, I have an issue were I allow one viewcontroller to be displayed in portrait and landscape, however when the user hits the back button I want to switch the apps orientation back to portrait. At present if the user hits the back button when its in landscape mode the rest of the application stays in landscape mode, has anyone came across a solution for auto-rotating?

[EDIT]

The effect is similar to what occurs when use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];` but this is a hidden API method :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I got from your question is you want to rotate only one view  portrait and landscape.  If that is what you want, then just go to method 
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation

and then return true then your only that view will rotate.

Comment: thanks for quick reply. I use the 'shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation' to detect when the user rotates the device. The trouble am having is when the view that can be rotated is in landscape mode and the user presses the back button, the rest of the application is then displayed in landscape which it hasn't been designed for.

Comment: all the other controller should  return 'code'   return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait); then it should be displayed in portrait mode.

Comment: Thanks iqbal, you are a star. I was returning NO in the other view controller, switched it to the above code and it worked perfect!