# iPhone:Device Orientation problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

HI in my iPHone App I facing problem for  the device orientation

[image]

screen 1

now On click of next button, it is displaying screen2 that is fine

[image]
        screen 2

now clicking on back when I can return to original screen it is not showing properly

[image]

what could be the problem?
how can I solve it?

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361799/rotate-to-portrait-orientation-when-back-button-pressed)

Comment: How are you doing your navigation? Are you using a navigation controller? or are you doing this manually by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

ViewController responsible for view that have Place and Food fields should have method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```