# How to change interface orientation from landscape to portrait when back button is tapped in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, screen-orientation

I have this project which requires to have a landscape orientation to view a graph and once the back button is tapped, it should return to the portrait orientation to view menus `Daily Graph` and `Carcadian Graph` . When user taps the `Daily Graph` it shows the graph in landscape orientation, the tendency user will hold his phone in landscape view and when `back` button is tap to return to the menu portrait orientation runs smoothly, but when user taps `Carcadian Graph` it shows the graph in landscape orientation, the tendency, user will hold his phone in landscape view and when `back` button is tap to return in `menuVC`, it just stay in landscape orientation which it should be portrait. How can I fix it, need some help since I am new in Objective C. Thank  you

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if (self.orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        UINavigationController *navController =(UINavigationController*)[self.tabBarController selectedViewController];
    UIViewController *dispViewController = navController.viewControllers.lastObject;

        if ([dispViewController.nibName isEqualToString:@"dailyGraph_vc"] == YES || [dispViewController.nibName isEqualToString:@"circadianGraph_vc"] == YES)
        {
           return 0;
        }
        else
          {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
          }
       }
      else
    {
      return 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: do you want to force one viewController to landscape?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate to Portrait Orientation when back button pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361799/rotate-to-portrait-orientation-when-back-button-pressed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:@(UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) forKey:@"orientation"];` on `viewWillDisappear` or somewhere else. It supports UIView animate block

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it and it works when the `AutoRotate` in my iPhone is locked, but when it is unlocked. It is not working.